# Index and Match a Subset Index in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match

I find the MAX of a metric called Positive Gamma (column J), and a corresponding value called Strike (column A) using MATCH. This match is the Key Gamma Strike.

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A, MATCH(MAX($J$2:$J), $J$2:$J, 0), 0)
```

Now I need to find the max Positive Gamma among all strikes above the Key Gamma Strike.

For example, if the Key Gamma Strike is 380, and the strike range goes to 400, I need to find the strike between 381 and 400 with the highest Positive Gamma.

I find the row location for each strike above the Key Gamma Strike, placing it into column K, as follows:

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( IF( MATCH($A$2:$A$550, $A$2:$A$550, 1) > MATCH(MAX($J$2:$J$550), $J$2:$J, 0), Match($A$2:$A$550, $A$2:$A$550, 1), "") ,0, 0), )
```

I'm struggling with finding the highest positive gamma from this range, and the corresponding strike.

There may be a better way to get this, I'm just not sure how. Feedback appreciated.

Here's a file with data matching the above formulas: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VGGjd1f47yCz9mvDHqRFEFYWJTq0w-Y8Mf8iGqFgO28/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is a blank sheet created specifically for this question.  Paste some sample data there and it'll be easier to help.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OClNsWjS9qCafeZygIkMrlJ743t81daQ7MGTtdaM59I/edit

Comment: Sorry about that -- I've added a link to original post providing access to a test file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have the Key Gamma Strike value on the cell K1, you could use the following array formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(IF($A:$A>$K$1;$J:$J;"")))
```

[You can find an example here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SNqsSkM05wJiQGLnCsIfl5WdiJKZN0Z2CqewVhLBXjs/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. That works. Is it necessary to find the two values separately? I found trying to combine both operations into a single formula got complex for my skill level - but perhaps that's not a good way to go about it.

Comment: It's possible to combine in just one formula. What is the final value that you're trying to get?

Comment: It is the value found by INDEX($A2:$A,MATCH($L$5,$J2:$J,0)) - i.e. the column A value that corresponds to MAX value from column J.

Comment: I have updated my sample file with a result in just one cell, please confirm if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: That does it. Thank you. In my own attempt, I think I had the inner index / match statements wrong.